# Written in column X for rows for which an email has been sent successfully

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I followed this tutorial to write a script to send a confirmation email after getting a new google form submission: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2z13YE3kJg

Here is my script after made some edits:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendMail() {
  var email = 0;
  var name = 1;
  var phone = 2;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form1");

  var data = ws.getRange("B2:D" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  
  data.forEach(function(row){

    emailTemp.fullname = row [name];
    emailTemp.phone = row [phone];
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    var emailSent = row[4];
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row [email],
      "Thank you!",
      "Your email doesn't support HTML.",
      {name: "Email App", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );

    sheet.getRange(startRange + i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    }

  });

}
```

Also, I followed this google developers tutorial to add an automatic written in column after getting new submission but it did not work with me:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

When I run the script I get this error:
[image: error]

I added a trigger of ***Event*** **= On form submit**
[image: trigger]
So, with that, the email is sent automatically after someone submits the form and it works well, but I need to write **EMAIL_SENT** in column **F** once the email is sent.

Here is the HTML email I have used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <p>Hello <?= fullname ?>,</p>
    <p>The phone number we have on file is <?= phone ?>. Please reply if it's incorrect.</p>
    <p>Best regards,<br>Email App Team</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Google Sheet that I want the **EMAIL_SENT** to be written in Column **F** automatically after auto-sending email when someone submits his information on my Google Form:
[image: example]

Comment: what's wrong with sheet.getRange( i + startRow, 6).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");  you will have to add an index to the loop which is the second param.  In your code startRange is undefined

Comment: Thanks @Cooper for your answer, but sorry I'm just a beginner on this, for that I've followed some tutorials, can you help me with the last part of your answer about how I can add an index to the loop, because I already added `sheet.getRange( i + startRow, 6).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");` but I don't know how I can do the rest.

Comment: When you wrote `sheet.getRange`, did you meant `ws.getRange`?

Comment: You are currently only reading 3 columns so there is no row[3] or row[4]

Comment: @cmolina yes I mean the ws, but I tried to change sheet to ws but still have the same issue

Comment: @Cooper I just modified the script `var data = ws.getRange("B2:F" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();` but I got the error after click on run

Comment: @Cooper check this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDcP3.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sendMail() {
  const emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form1");
  const startRow = 2
  const data = sh.getRange(startRow, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    emailTemp.fullname = row[1];
    emailTemp.phone = row[2];
    let htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    let emailSent = row[4];
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[0],"Thank you!","Your email doesn't support HTML.",{ name: "Email App", htmlBody: htmlMessage });
      sh.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work with me :( check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnTm.png

Comment: I did change startRange which is what you had to startRow because that's what I wanted to change it to.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper, it works well, I really appreciate your help.